How do I rotate the grid into multiple objects?
I need to rotate the grid around its axis. But I have a lot of grids for each polygon. When building a grid in polygons, each grid cell rotates, and I need the entire grid on the polygon to be rotated, for example, by 10 degrees. When using a grid line, they also rotate around the center of each line.

I used the assembled model and I do not know how to specify the input data for the centroids of each grid.
I also used the article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282724/creating-a-regular-polygon-grid-over-a-spatial-extent-rotated-by-a-given-angle.
It suits me the most, but I do not know the R language. How can this be done in Python or in models?

Each grid is a unique layer?

no, this is a single shp layer with many polygons

Your attribute table hold some polygon id to identify which grid polygons belongs to which polygon?

The polygon has a unique key. The grid does not inherit this key when it is created, but I can assign it to polygons.


Menu Vector -> Research Tools -> Create grid...
Menu Processing -> Toolbox -> Rotate
For the Rotation anchor point, you can either:

manually click somewhere in the center of the grid or
create the grid's centroid with Menu Processing -> Toolbox -> Geometry by expression and this expression:  centroid (layer_property (@layer,'extent')). Then activate snapping and select the created point.




If you have a lot of grids on the same layer and as long as they do not overlap, buffer/dissolve them by 0 and create the centroid of each buffer. Then use this centroid as input for Rotation anchor point.
If buffers overlap, you must have an attribute value (id, see comment by @Bera) to group cells together to a grid.
Red: rotated grid


Thank you for your advice. But I can't use manual rotation since I can have more than 500 grids.

You can run the tool in batch mode for automatic rotation of hundreds of layers. If you want to include the creation of the centroid, create a model and run that in batch mode.

In qgis, layer autocomplete is very inconvenient. And all my polygons are in the same layer, and the center of the polygons is different.  That is, I have 2 options: first, I need to calculate the center of each polygon and then build and rotate the grid describing the boundaries of each polygon. And the second one is to immediately build a grid with the desired slope. as in the article  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282724/creating-a-regular-polygon-grid-over-a-spatial-extent-rotated-by-a-given-angle  but on python.

OK, maybe you should rethink your workflow to make the process easier. First, extract all polygon features to a separate layer (so each layer contains only one polygon; use Split vector layer: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgissplitvectorlayer), than create a grid, rotate it, and then merge the resulting grid-layers back into one layer. The other way round is doable, but more complicate.

The function of merging lines in the grid layer helped me. After merging, each grid object is rotated in its entirety. Thanks, Babel!  but my my model stopped working in combining layers into one. I don't know why yet . I'll figure it out.
